# git: error: src refspec main does not match any

Tags: git, github

I was trying to use git via VSCode, and because I didn't know how to use Git on VSCode, it messed up everything.
Then I tried to use CMD (Windows) as usual. I am learning, and I've never seen this kind of error before, so I don't know how to solve this.

But it's showing these errors when I try to push to the main branch:

```
error: src refspec main does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'myPathToRepo'
```

I tried:

- I tried with another branch and it was working fine but I want to use the main branch
- I even tried deleting the git folder and initiating it again

I've seen other posts on StackOverflow and mostly they say "first commit and then push because this error arises when you're pushing without committing".

After deleting the `.git/` folder and restarting, it starts to show this same error

```
>git push
fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin master

>git push -u origin main
error: src refspec main does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'myPathToRepo'
```

This is my first commit:

```
[master (root-commit) 061a06e] first commit
```

PS. I only have 'main' branch.

Commands that I ran:

```
git init
git remote add origin 'pathToMyRepo'
git add -A
git commit -m "first commit"
git push
git push -u origin main
```

Please help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+error%3A+src+refspec+main+does+not+match+any

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You don't have a branch called `main`. You have a branch called `master`.

Either push with the correct name:

```
git push -u origin master
```

Or change your local branch name to main and use that:

```
git branch -m main
git push -u origin main
```

Comment: after doing so it's showing this error. 
>To pathToMyRepo
 ! [rejected]        main -> main (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'pathToMyRepo'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Comment: Well, did you do what the error message suggests?

Comment: I tried git pull. then it said "There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to rebase against." then I tried >git pull origin main, then It said "fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories". Then I did "git pull origin main --allow-unrelated-histories" and this solved it. Then I did 'git push -u origin main and that's it, I can use it like normal now. I really need to focus on errors rather than just making it work so next time I won't have issues resolving them. But thanks, I'll select this as the answer to help others

Answer (score 27):

**just make sure you have SOMTHING in your folder to commit**

1. git init
2. git remote add origin 'pathToYourRepo'
3. git add .
4. git commit -m "first commit"
5. git push -u origin main

Answer (score 16):

In my case I just had forgot to commit a first time

The solution was to `git commit -am "initial commit"`

I wish the error message were more explicit

Comment: One _clue_ is that when you type `git branch` before you have added and committing any files for the first time, it will return nothing, i.e. it shows you have no branch and are not on any branch, i.e. the branch **main** doesn't exist yet locally.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to launch VSCode *after* having set up:

```
git config --global init.defaultbranch main
```

That way, your default local branch created will be indeed `main`, and not `master`, when you initialize a new repository, and make your first commit with VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

When on GitLab use:

**Push an existing Git repository**

```
cd existing_repo
git remote rename origin old-origin
git remote add origin https://git.fhict.nl/I872272/test3.git
git push -u origin --all
git push -u origin --tags
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem but with code I can solve it

```
git commit -m “your commit”
git remote add origin ( your repo )
git branch -M main 
git push
git push -uf origin main
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35796587)

Answer (score -1):

```
$ git config --global user.mail
hacker@DESKTOP-4HNH4GR MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Desktop/HACKER git (main)
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/hacker/OneDrive/Desktop/HACKER git/
.git/
hacker@DESKTOP-4HNH4GR MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Desktop/HACKER git (master)
$ git add .
hacker@DESKTOP-4HNH4GR MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Desktop/HACKER git (master)
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/STARLA712/naistudio.git
hacker@DESKTOP-4HNH4GR MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Desktop/HACKER git (master)
$ git branch -m main
hacker@DESKTOP-4HNH4GR MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Desktop/HACKER git (main)
$ git remote rename origin old-origin
hacker@DESKTOP-4HNH4GR MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Desktop/HACKER git (main)
$ git remote add origin "https://github.com/STARLA712/naistudio.git"
$ git push -u origin --all
No refs in common and none specified; doing nothing.
Perhaps you should specify a branch.
Everything up-to-date
hacker@DESKTOP-4HNH4GR MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Desktop/HACKER git (main)
$ git push -u origin --tags
No refs in common and none specified; doing nothing.
Perhaps you should specify a branch.
Everything up-to-date
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [answer]. In particular, please make sure that your answers address the question being asked. It's unclear how the commands shown above, which are essentially a generic "how to start with Git" without any explanation or context, are supposed to answer the question.